# lsやcd等、軽めのコマンドの実行に時間がかかることがある。

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

lsやcd等、軽めのコマンドの実行にやけに時間がかかることがあります。10~20秒程度です。
環境はubuntu20.04です。

この現象は起こったり起こらなかったりで、操作ディレクトリに関わらず起こるため、動作負荷が原因ではないと思っています。

以前も同様の現象が起きたことがあり、そのときはgnomeの設定のリセット？かなにかで問題解消できたのですが、肝心のコマンドを忘れてしまいました。

なにかご存知の方いらっしゃれば教えてくださると助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `cd` はシェルのビルトインコマンドだから時間がかかるとは思えないっス。普通でない方法で ubuntu をインストールしている（仮想環境とか）？　その辺、今の質問本文に書かれていないあたりに原因があるとしたら第三者であるオイラたち読者では推測すらできないです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
インストールについては詳しくは覚えておりませんが、変わった手順は踏んでいません。

Comment: シェルのプロンプトにGItの状態を表示するなどの設定をしていますか？ `find /` などとした場合、すんなり終りますか？ メモリやストレージの空きはありますか？

Comment: `locate`という, ファイル検索コマンドがインストールされている場合,
(デフォでは)一日一回全てのファイルやフォルダーをデータベースに登録する処理が走ります。
`locate`コマンドのデータベースを作成するのは `mlocate` …
`find /etc/cron* -name "*mlocate*"` で何か見つかるならそれかも